# Map flatten and flatmap not equivalent

Tags: scala, dictionary, case-class

I thought that [Scala construct `map(f).flatten` was equivalent to `flatMap(f)`](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/). But with this example, it is not the case. I wonder what is the role of the case class in it. If I use integers,  both are equivalent. But in my case, I cannot.

```
case class CTest(v: Int)
val s = Set(Map(CTest(0) -> List(0, 3), CTest(1) -> List(0, 2)))
val possibilities = s flatMap { m =>
  val mapping = m flatMap {
    case (label, destNodes) => destNodes map {
      case nodes => (label, nodes) }
  }
  mapping
}
possibilities
```

Yields

```
Set((CTest(0),3), (CTest(1), 2))
```

whereas

```
case class CTest(v: Int)
val s = Set(Map(CTest(0) -> List(0, 3), CTest(1) -> List(0, 2)))
val possibilities = s flatMap { m =>
  val mapping = m map {
    case (label, destNodes) => destNodes map {
      case nodes => (label, nodes) }
  }
  mapping.flatten
}
possibilities
```

yields

```
Set((CTest(0),0), (CTest(0),3), (CTest(1),0), (CTest(1),2))
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at implementation of `flatMap`:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  def builder = bf(repr) // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
  val b = builder
  for (x <- this) b ++= f(x).seq
  b.result
}
```

Result of `flatMap` depends on original collection type and result type of function `f`. In first example you generate sequence of tuples from map, so that compiler picks implementation like `CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], (C, D), Map[C, D]]`, which provides builder for `Map`, that causes overwriting of same keys.

You can directly convert map to plain iterable, that will yield result you want:

```
case class CTest(v: Int)
val s = Set(Map(CTest(0) -> List(0, 3), CTest(1) -> List(0, 2)))
val possibilities = s flatMap { m =>
  val mapping = m.toIterable.flatMap {
    case (label, destNodes) => destNodes map {
      case nodes => (label, nodes) }
  }
  mapping
}
possibilities
```

Answer (score 10):

This happens due to intermediate data structures.

I'll take simple version of your example.

```
val m = Map(CTest(0) -> List(0, 3), CTest(1) -> List(0, 2))
```

When using `flatMap` you directly create a `Map[CTest, Int]`

```
scala> m flatMap {
 |     case (label, destNodes) => destNodes map {
 |       case nodes => (label, nodes) }
 |   }
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[CTest,Int] = Map(CTest(0) -> 3, CTest(1) -> 2)
```

In here, due to the uniqueness of the keys of `Map`, `(CTest(0), 0)` and `(CTest(1), 0)` will be dropped from the result. when you `flatMap` it over set, you will get a `Set` of `Tuples` which were in the `Map`.

In your second example, you map and flatten.

```
val mapping = m map {
 |     case (label, destNodes) => destNodes map {
 |       case nodes => (label, nodes) }
 |   }
mapping: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[(CTest, Int)]] = List(List((CTest(0),0), (CTest(0),3)), List((CTest(1),0), (CTest(1),2)))

mapping.flatten
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(CTest, Int)] = List((CTest(0),0), (CTest(0),3), (CTest(1),0), (CTest(1),2))
```

There isn't any `Map` or another uniqueness preserved data structure created in the middle of the process. So values are not dropped.