# Is there any difference between flatten and flatMap(identity)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, flatmap

```
scala> List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4))
res18: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4))

scala> res18.flatten
res19: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res18.flatMap(identity)
res20: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Is there any difference between these two functions? When is it appropriate to use one over the other? Are there any tradeoffs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can view `flatMap(identity)` as `map(identity).flatten`. (Of course it is not implemented that way, since it would take two iterations).

`map(identity)` gives you the same collection, so in the end it is the same as only `flatten`.

I would personally stick to `flatten`, since it is shorter/easier to understand and designed to exactly do this.

Answer (score 6):

> Conceptually there is no difference in the result... `flatMap` is taking
>   bit more time to produce same result...

#### I will show it more practically with an example of `flatMap`, `map` & then `flatten` and `flatten`

```
object Test extends App {
  // flatmap
  println(timeElapsed(List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8)).flatMap(identity)))
  // map and then flatten
  println(timeElapsed(List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8)).map(identity).flatten))
  // flatten
  println(timeElapsed(List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8)).flatten))

  /**
   * timeElapsed
   */
  def timeElapsed[T](block: => T): T = {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val res = block
    val totalTime = System.nanoTime - start
    println("Elapsed time: %1d nano seconds".format(totalTime))
    res
  }
}
```

---

***Both `flatMap` and `flatten` executed with same result after repeating several times***

#### *Conclusion : `flatten` is efficient*

```
Elapsed time: 2915949 nano seconds
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
Elapsed time: 1060826 nano seconds
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
Elapsed time: 81172 nano seconds
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, there is no difference.  Practically, `flatten` is more efficient, and conveys a clearer intent.

Generally, you don't use `identity` directly.  It's more there for situations like it getting passed in as a parameter, or being set as a default.  It's possible for the compiler to optimize it out, but you're risking a superfluous function call for every element.

You would use `flatMap` when you need to do a `map` (with a function other than `identity`) immediately followed by a `flatten`.

Comment: The last sentence ("You would use..") is misleading, `flatmap` can't always be replace with `map` + `flatten` and it normally conveys a different computation

Comment: @Chirlo, I think you are mistaken there, but I'm willing to admit if I am wrong.  Can you please provide a counterexample?

Comment: with `map` + `flatten` you'll always get a  `List` with the same number of elements as the original. With `flatmap` you could can do more manipulations, like `list.flatmap( x => if (x > 2 ) List(x,x,x,x) else List())`. This would yield ( from the OPs example) : `List(3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)`.  You can implement `filter`, `takeWhile`.... in terms of `flatMap`, which you can't do with `map+flatten`

Comment: Your first example with `map+flatten` is `list.map(x=>if (x>2) List(x,x,x,x) else List()).flatten`.  `filter` is `list.map(x => if (pred(x)) List(x) else List()).flatten`.

Comment: Oh, ok, I missunderstood the example, but you can get [into situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215518/scala-map-flatten-and-flatmap-not-equivalent) where both are not equivalent, because of scala's signature of `flatmap` (with `CanBuildFrom`).