# Inverting mapping from list elements to to String in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to Scala I was trying to flatten the list and invert the mapping. For example I have a map as below :

```
Map("abc"->List(1,2,3),"def"->List(1,5,6))
```

I want the result to be :

```
Map(1->List("abc","def"),2->List("abc"),3->List("abc"),5->List("def"),6->List("def"))
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> val mm = Map("abc"->List(1,2,3),"def"->List(1,5,6))
mm.toList.flatMap{ case (s, l) => l.map(ll => (ll, s))}.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (i, l) => (i, l.map(_._2))}

mm: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(abc -> List(1, 2, 3), def -> List(1, 5, 6))

scala> res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(5 -> List(def), 1 -> List(abc, def), 6 -> List(def), 2 -> List(abc), 3 -> List(abc))

scala>
```

UPDATE:
A slightly different solution I like better:

```
mm.toList.flatMap{ case (s, l) => 
  l.map(li => (li, s))
}.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, List[String]]){ 
  case (m, (i, s)) => m.updated(i, s :: m.getOrElse(i, List.empty))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Denis Makarenko. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do in simple way

```
val data = Map("abc"->List(1,2,3),"def"->List(1,5,6))

val list = data.toList.flatMap(x => {
  x._2.map(y => (y, x._1))
}).groupBy(_._1).map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._2)))
```

Output:

```
(5,List(def))
(1,List(abc, def))
(6,List(def))
(2,List(abc))
(3,List(abc))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where's the `1 -> abc` relationship? It appears to have been lost.

Comment: Hi @ShankarKoirala Could you please explain me how the execution differs when using toList and when not using toList

Comment: @KavyaVishwanathB  toList method changes the map to List of tuples, `Map[String,List[Int]]`  to `List[(String, List[Int])]`, If you do not change Map to list you wont be able to store two keys such as `(1, abc)` `(1,def)`, in map it updates the value of 1, So if you convert to list of tuples it works.

Comment: Hope this helped!

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way of doing this:

```
  Map("abc" -> List(1,2,3), "def"-> List(1,5,6)).flatMap {
    case (key, values) => values.map(elem => Map(elem -> key))
  }.flatten.foldRight(Map.empty[Int, List[String]]) { (elem, acc) =>
    val (key, value) = elem
    if (acc.contains(key)) {
      val newValues = acc(key) ++ List(value)
      (acc - key) ++ Map(key -> newValues)
    } else {
      acc ++ Map(key -> List(value))
    }
  }
```

So basically what I do is to go over the initial Map, transform that to a tuple and then do a foldRight and group identical keys into the accumulator.

This is a bit verbose than the other solutions posted here, but I prefer to avoid using underscores in my implementations as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to invert the `Map`:

```
val m = Map("abc" -> List(1, 2, 3), "def" -> List(1, 5, 6))

m.map{ case (k, v) => v.map((_, k)) }.flatten.
  groupBy(_._1).mapValues( _.map(_._2) )

// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]] = Map(
//   5 -> List(def), 1 -> List(abc, def), 6 -> List(def), 2 -> List(abc), 3 -> List(abc)
// )
```

Comment: That's one case when m.map(...).flatten is not the same as m.flatMap(...). It may be tempting to refactor it by mistake, so I find m.toList.flatMap(...) a bit safer in this regard.

Comment: @Denis Makarenko, could you provide an example where `flatMap` is safer to use than `map/flatten`?  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215518/map-flatten-and-flatmap-not-equivalent) which shows the other way though.